TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')
I am trying to create a simple IVR using Microsoft Azure Communication Services. I have created a function to answer an incoming call, and a function to handle the event during the call such as playing an audio, getting input from the user, etc.
When a call is answered, an audio file will be played. This part of my functions works fine. The next part is that the user/caller will hear another audio file and will be asked to answer a question. I used the Call Automation package and speech recognition, but I got the following error when getting the inputs from the user:
"Error processing event: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')".
The function is as follows:
    if (eventType === 'Microsoft.Communication.CallConnected') {
            const callConnectionId = eventData.callConnectionId;

            // Play an audio 
            const playSource = { url: "...", kind: "fileSource" };
            await callAutomationClient.getCallConnection(callConnectionId).getCallMedia().playToAll([playSource]);

            // another audio source
            const playSource = { URL: "...", kind: "fileSource" };

            const recognizeOptions = {   
                playPrompt: playSource, 
                initialSilenceTimeoutInSeconds: 10, 
                interruptPrompt: true, 
                operationContext: "OpenQuestionSpeech", 
                kind: "callMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions"
            }; 

            await callAutomationClient.getCallConnection(callConnectionId).getCallMedia().startRecognizing(recognizeOptions); 
};

There seems to be a problem with kind: "callMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions" in the last line of the recognizeOptions typescript. I followed the instructions in Gather user input with Recognize action and CallMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions interface, but still got this error.
I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

There's no use of .kind anywhere in this code.

It's in the last line of recognizeOptions typescript. kind: "callMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions" @Barmar

The error is happening in some other code that contains something.kind. The error means that that something is undefined.

Can you post the complete block of the code it looks like the if statement block is not closed.

First of all, there is a missing comma operator in the line:
const playSource = { url: "..." kind: "fileSource" };

Also looking at the documentation, it appears that the startRecognizing function accepts two parameters targetParticipant and recognizeOptions, but you are passing recognizeOptions in place of targetParticipant. Try fixing this.

That fixed the error. I should have added the caller's phone number as the targetParticipant. Thanks!
